# Peewee auth failure

Tags: python, postgresql, peewee

I'm trying to connect my application to postgresql database through [peewee](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee).

`config.ini`:

```
[DEFAULT]
discord_key = apikey
# private token from discord developer porter
psql_user = postgres
# username for postgres database
psql_db = test
# database name
owner_id = owner
# discord user ID of bot installation owner.
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3033, in __enter__
    self.db.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3136, in connect
    self._initialize_connection(self._state.conn)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2970, in __exit__
    reraise(new_type, new_type(exc_value, *exc_args), traceback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/peewee.py", line 191, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3133, in connect
    self._state.set_connection(self._connect())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/playhouse/postgres_ext.py", line 471, in _connect
    conn = super(PostgresqlExtDatabase, self)._connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3866, in _connect
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
peewee.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

The [bot.py](https://github.com/the-brainiac-1869/Polytopia-ELO-Bot/blob/master/bot.py) file is here.

AFAIU peewee needs my psql password to authenticate the connection but I don't know how to pass the password in the config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got this code, but it looks like maybe it hardcodes the password? https://github.com/the-brainiac-1869/Polytopia-ELO-Bot/blob/master/modules/models.py#L25